# user access denied error in mysql connection

Tags: mysql, talend

I'm facing very bad situation in Mysql 5.7

I'm having username--> pop and password --> pop with database name "Home"

When I connect from workbench..its works fine.

When I connect through tmysqlinputconnection (TalendETL) (adding manually credentials in component) it works.

Problem is, when I try to connect the tmysqlinputconnection  with context parameters where values are coming from file

Shows error like this-----> Access denied for user 'pop'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

May I know please from where its coming ...?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

did you add the connection to the repository using metadata , and exported it has a context ? Then you have a "check" button . It could help you see if it comes from the values, of from the 'import-from-file' part.

Comment: Yes Ive tried with component having context variables as a credentials...but still same error.!!